# Though I am running apt-get update as sudo, I'm still getting permission denied

Tags: permissions, apt, sudo

Error:

> Could not open file
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
>   - open (13: Permission denied)

I'm looking for the reason and also solution...

Comment: What does the output of `ls -lah /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz` look like?  Maybe the output of `ls -lZ /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz` could be useful if you have selinux which could prevent access.

Comment: what did you typed in your terminal ?

Comment: Yes, I tried both **sudo** and **root**. and I got this output Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - open (13: Permission denied) and lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 106 Apr 25 09:22 /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz